# Output always 0 when involved int and double on c program

Tags: c

i'm trying to make a calculation for wages and the requirements as below:

- basic pay = 12.00 /hr
- OT (>40hrs)=1.5x pay per hr
- tax
- 15% first 300
- 20% 301<=payout<=450
- 25% >450

I declare the variables as follows:

- hours as hrs
- gross payment as gross
- taxed as tax
- total payout after deduction as pymt

I import my header as this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I define my constant as this

```
#define bsc 12.00
#define t300 0.15
#define t150 0.20
#define t_rest 0.25
#define OT 40
```

This is how i defined my function

```
int main()
{
    int hrs=0;
    double gross = 0.00;
    double tax = 0.00;
    double pymt = 0.00;
    printf("How many hours worked this week?\n");
    scanf("%i", &hrs);

    if (hrs <= 40)
        pymt = hrs * bsc;
    else
    {
        pymt = 40 * bsc;
        double OTpymt = (hrs - 40) * (bsc * 1.5);
        pymt += OTpymt;
    }
    
    if (gross <= 300)
    {
        tax = gross * t300;
    }
    
    else if (gross > 300 && gross <= 450)
    {
        tax = 300 * t150;
        tax += (gross - 300) * t150;
    }

    else if (gross > 450)
    {
        tax = 300 * t300;
        tax += 150 * t150;
        tax += (gross - 450) * t_rest;

    }

    pymt = gross - tax;
    printf("\ngross: %.2lf\n", gross);
    printf("tax: %.2lf\n", tax);
    printf("total pay: %.2lf", pymt);


    return 0;
}
```

When I debug and insert any value in user input, it always opt as 0.00.
and this is the image -->
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kga8F.png)

I need help without changing my int variable to other data type? took me days but still unable to find out the solution. i'm currently using c17. I had 4 different operating systems (Win10, Win11, Debian, Mac12) and it gives same outcome.

note: i tried %.2f for the specifier, and it still not working at all. also the same as i declare my constant as double.

Comment: You have `double gross = 0.00;` and there is no further assignment to `gross`,

Comment: @WeatherVane is right... You are calculating `gross` when working out the hours, but using the variable `pymt'.

Comment: You say "when I debug...". Are you using a debugger? If so, set breakpoints and inspect the values of your variables to test your assumptions.

Comment: thank you very much @WeatherVane for specifying all of the issue, my code is working after i followed your advise...

Comment: @chummer Aside: simplification `else if (gross > 300 && gross <= 450` --> `else if (gross <= 450`.  `gross > 300` test not needed as that is accounted for in `if (gross <= 300)`.

Comment: Word of warning from real life experience. Currency calcs should be done with "cents" (integers), not floating point. Small rounding issues accumulate unseen until you've got thousands (millions?) of records that are incorrect. Or, round after every calc and slow things down to a crawl... Think about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gross` is always 0.0, then `tax` is always zero, and `pymt` becomes zero as well `pymt = gross - tax;`

Answer (score 1):

[@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73813321/output-always-0-when-involved-int-and-double-on-c-program#comment130337129_73813321) posted the issue and solution:

> You have double gross = 0.00; and there is no further assignment to
> gross

Thank you very much for the help.